# If $f(t) = \sqrt{t^2+4}$, why does $\frac{d}{dx}[F(x)-F(0)] = f(x)-0=f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am learning about the fundamental theorem of calculus by watching the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeB5BWY0RlE). I am confused by part of the explanation. When the video says, if $f(t) = \sqrt{t^2+4}$, then $\frac{d}{dx}[F(x)-F(0)] = f(x)-0=f(x)$. I don't get why that is.

The way the math is wrriten out, it goes.

if $\frac{d}{dx}[\int^x_0 \sqrt{t^2+4}dt]$ then $f(t)=\sqrt{t^2+4}$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}[\int^x_0f(t)dt]$$
$$= \frac{d}{dx}[F(t) |^x_0]$$
$$=\frac{d}{dx}[F(x)-F(0)]$$
$$=f(x)-0$$
$$=f(x)$$

The explanation for why $\frac{d}{dx}F(0)=0$ is that it's a constant. However, I don't understand why it's a constant.

I know that $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$, and I *think* that $\int\sqrt{t^2+4}=\int(t^2+4)^{1/2}=\frac{(t^2+4)^{3/2}}{3/2}=\frac{2(t^2+4)^{3/2}}{3} +C$, according to the rule, $\int x^ndx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$.

But plugging in $0$ for $t$ on $\frac{2(t^2+4)^{3/2}}{3} +C$ doesn't seem to achieve anything. It becomes $0 + C$. However, I'm not sure if I should just ignore the $C$.

Obviously, if $c$ is a constant, $\frac{d}{dx}c = 0$, but I'm not sure why that's relevant here.

*Why is $F(0)=0$?*

Comment: @Jo' That was a typo, I have fixed it.

Comment: @egreg I am trying to find out why $F(0)$ is a constant function.

Comment: It's because it's $F$ evaluated at a particular value $x=0$, I believe. Whatever the result, it will be a number, a constant.

Comment: @LuminousNutria It's the value of $F$ at $0$. In the above example, $g(0)=-3$.

Comment: $F$ is the function, but $F(0)$ is the value in $0$ of that function, this is immutable, in other words a constant.

Comment: So basically, if $c$ is a constant, while $F(x)$ is not a constant function, $F(c)$ is a constant function, by virtue of having no variables except for $C$?

Comment: $F$ is *some* antiderivative - it's just a function such that $F' = f$. $\frac{2(t^2 + 4)^{3/2}}{3} + C$  denotes *all* antiderivatives. We need to choose one of them - for example, corresponding to $C = 0$.

Comment: @mihaild So what values are replaced by $0$? $C$ or $t$?

Comment: We substitute $C = 0$ to get some concrete antiderivative. Then we substitute $t = 0$ to get value of this antiderivative at point $0$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Why is that?

Comment: @mihaild Okay, I think I got it. So, basically $F(c)$ replaces both $t$ and $C$ with $c$?

Comment: Why is it a constant? Any time you evaluate a single function at a particular point, you're just going to get a number out. I'm not really sure how to explain this any clearer than that.

Comment: @LuminousNutria no, you need to fix $C$ before you get any **function** $F$ to talk about. Indefinite integral is a set of all antiderivatives, and $F$ denotes some specific element from this set.

Comment: @mihaild what do you mean "fix $C$"?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I am confused because $F(x)$ has two variables, $x$ and $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$, but more importantly for your question, $F(x)$ is just a function. What happens when you plug some value, say $0$, into a function? You get a number. We don't know what that number is, but it doesn't matter, because when you take the derivative of a number, you get zero, regardless of what it is. That's what they mean when they say, "because it's a constant." $F(0)$ is a constant, so $\frac{d}{dx}(F(0)) = 0$.